# Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services

I have report Which default runs for current month, on the report itself i have created two labels called Prev and Next. if i click on Prev label then it should create a Report for March month and if i click on Next it should give the report for the Month May. How can i achieve this in Reporting services .Kindly help  me with this one?

Answer (score 4):

If you're not doing so already, make sure the report accepts a date parameter (which defaults to today's date) and use that to determine which month to retrieve the data for.

The rest should be relatively easy:

First, right-click on your "Next" TextBox and bring up its properties dialog. There's a tab there called "Navigation". On the Navigation tab you can specify a report to which that TextBox should link ("Jump to report"). Choose the same report that you're currently working on.

Now click the "Parameters" button to specify the parameters you want to pass to the report you're linking to. Choose the date parameter from the list of available parameters, and for its value, use an expression like this:

```
=dateadd("m", 1, Parameters!Date.Value)
```

(I've assumed that your parameter's name is "Date" there.)

So you're effectively linking to the same report, but adding one month to the date it's running for. Obviously the "Prev" TextBox works the same way except pass -1 to the dateadd call.

For a more ".NET" expression, you could also try this code:

```
=CDate(Parameters!Date.Value).AddMonths(1)
```

I'm fairly certain that will accomplish the same thing, and might be a tad more readable.

You might also want to style those TextBoxes so that they look like hyperlinks to the end user (blue/underlined, perhaps, depending on your standards).